Why Gifford-Mcmahon cycle's Refrigeration Effect is $Q=V(P_1-P_2)$?

This extract is from Advances in Cryogenic Engineering (Vol 11). They do give an explanation for my question in Volume 6, but I am struggling to understand that

It's from the first law of thermodynamics! This says that ideal refrigeration is  $$\Delta U = Q_\mathrm{c}-W$$
Where $\Delta U$ is the change in internal energy, $Q_\mathrm{c}$ is the cooling energy and $W$ is the work being done by the expanding volume. In the ideal case there is no change in internal energy, $$Q_\mathrm{c} = \oint dW = (P_\mathrm{h} - P_\mathrm{l})V$$
Which is the description for the work done by the gas on the displacer. The contour integral is shown with the arrows in the PV work diagram below!

A real GM cooler has many different losses from pressure drops, friction on displacer seals, dead zones etc. but this is the theoretical maximum!

Hi. Thanks for replying. Is it possible to prove why this is true? Generally, the area enclosed by the loop corresponds to work input for the Carnot cycle and such cycles. Why does it equal the cooling load for the G-M cycle?

Hi, reversing the Carnot cycle causes cooling, that's the intuition for what is going on in the volume of gas between the cold tip and the displacer.

Agreed. But even in the reverse Carnot cycle, the area enclosed by the loop is the work input required and not the cooling load. The cooling load is rather calculated as TL*(S2-S1) where TL is the cold reservoir temperature and S2 and S1 are the two entropy values between which the reverse Carnot cycle operates.
However, for the G-M Cycle, apparently the cooling load is equal to the area enclose by the loop. This is what I am struggling to grasp.
